# Reading XML into Array, keep getting error

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, parsing

I want to take an XML file and put its data into an array in C#

My code:

```
XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
XMLDoc.Load("C:/Scripts/example.xml");
string[] bans = XMLDoc.Descendants("ban").Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

But, I keep getting this error:

> 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for
>   'Descendants' and no extension method 'Descendants' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my xml file if its relevant:

```
<championSelect>
    <blue>
        <ban order="1">Darius</ban>
        <ban order="3">Elise</ban>
        <ban order="5">Twisted Fate</ban>
        <pick order="1">Gragas</pick>
        <pick order="4">Shen</pick>
        <pick order="5">Shyvanna</pick>
    </blue>
    <red>
        <ban order="2">Jayce</ban>
        <ban order="4">Zac</ban>
        <ban order="6">Thresh</ban>
        <pick order="2">Draven</pick>
        <pick order="3">Ryze</pick>
    </red>
</championSelect>
```

I think it has to do with the .Descendants but I can't say for certain.  I've tried a lot of the other solutions here on stack overflow to no avail.  I welcome another approach if neccessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LINQ looks fine, however you're using an `XmlDocument` (from the `System.Xml` namespace). For the LINQ to work you want to use an `XDocument` instead, which is part of the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("C:/Scripts/example.xml");
string[] bans = doc.Descendants("ban")
                   .Select(element => element.Value)
                   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing your LINQ reference, perhaps?  Try adding

```
Using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Comment: unfortunately, I am already using System.Xml.Linq; as well as System.Linq;  thanks though

Comment: Perhaps you mean to be using XDocuments instead of XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you should be using the XDocument class, which is part of the System.XML.Linq namesapace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx